# Compiling C program: Dynamical type definition leads to errors

Tags: c, makefile

I wrote a dovecot plugin in C the last days. My source code itself seems to be quite fine, but I'm currently wondering how to compile it or how to have a more dynamical Makefile.

The problem is, that whenever I try to compile, I get the error `Error: unknown type name: »uoff_t«`

The problem is, that this type is defined in one referenced library in this way:

```
#if defined (HAVE_UOFF_T)
/* native support */
#elif defined (UOFF_T_INT)
typedef unsigned int uoff_t;
#elif defined (UOFF_T_LONG)
typedef unsigned long uoff_t;
#elif defined (UOFF_T_LONG_LONG)
typedef unsigned long long uoff_t;
#else
#  error uoff_t size not set
#endif
```

Within dovecot's Autoconf these variables are set based on another type:

```
AC_CHECK_TYPE(uoff_t, [
  have_uoff_t=yes
  AC_DEFINE(HAVE_UOFF_T,, Define if you have a native uoff_t type)
], [
  have_uoff_t=no
])

AC_TYPEOF(off_t, long int long-long)
case "$typeof_off_t" in
  int)
    offt_max=INT_MAX
    uofft_fmt="u"
    if test "$have_uoff_t" != "yes"; then
      AC_DEFINE(UOFF_T_INT,, Define if off_t is int)
    fi
    offt_bits=`expr 8 \* $ac_cv_sizeof_int`
    ;;
  long)
    offt_max=LONG_MAX
    uofft_fmt="lu"
    if test "$have_uoff_t" != "yes"; then
      AC_DEFINE(UOFF_T_LONG,, Define if off_t is long)
    fi
    offt_bits=`expr 8 \* $ac_cv_sizeof_long`
    ;;
  "long long")
    offt_max=LLONG_MAX
    uofft_fmt="llu"
    if test "$have_uoff_t" != "yes"; then
      AC_DEFINE(UOFF_T_LONG_LONG,, Define if off_t is long long)
    fi
    offt_bits=`expr 8 \* $ac_cv_sizeof_long_long`
    ;;
  *)
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Unsupported off_t type])
    ;;
esac
```

So after all my question is, whether I can have this stuff in an equivalent way in my Makefile without using Automake.

My goal is to check, whether uoff_t is defined already somewhere (for HAVE_UOFF_T) or how the type off_t is defined (for the other parameters).
Any ideas, or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question.  Is it that you want your Makefile to specify `UOFF_T_INT` and the like?

Comment: Correct. Sorry for not making this clear. Will immediatly improve the question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously what I tried to do seems not to be possible.
I ended up digging myself into autoconf and reusing dovecot's generic definition.

Thanks anyway!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

My first idea is that if it is a Dovecot plugin (which I know nothing about) doesn't it have to include Dovecot include files?

Wouldn't those include files have already been through the Dovecot autoconf and have all the right values for the uoff_t type?

So the first thing that I would try is to just rely on the Dovecot definition.

I suppose the other thing to do is something that I have done on occasion. Reproduce the autoconf tests inside your Makefile. But I have to warn you it tends to look really ugly. Sort of like this:

```
TESTOPTTMP:=$(shell mkdir -p tmp; mktemp tmp/test_opt_XXXXXXXXXX)
CFLAGS += $(shell (echo '\#include <pthread.h>'; echo '__thread int global; int main() { global = 1; return 0; }') | gcc -x c -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread -o $(TESTOPTTMP) - >>/dev/stderr 2>&1; $(TESTOPTTMP) && echo '-DHAVE_TLS'; rm -f $(TESTOPTTMP))
```

That was for testing compiler support for `__thread`. Ugly, isn't it.

Comment: Hi Zan, thanks for your input. Unfortunately, the code I posted above already is Dovecot's. The first snippet is uoff_t's definition in Dovecot's compat.h, the second belongs to the corresponding configure.in. What I would like to do, is rebuilding those checks (e.g. `AC_CHECK_TYPE`) in my Makefile and set the parameters there for the definition in compat.h. But I wonder what that would look like...